# After violating US student visa and deportation, could I complete my studies in Canada?

Tags: usa, canada, student-visa

I was in the USA from 2015 until this January (2019) on F1 status. While I was re-entering the US, I was taken to secondary inspection by Customs and Immigration. They checked my cell phone and they found text messages regarding a job which I was doing. I was working in a convenience store which was not legal. Finally, after 8 hours of conversation, they deported me and banned me for 5 years.

I was pursuing a Bachelor's in Information Technology and I had two more semesters to finish my course. Now, since I was deported, is there any way I can complete my studies in Canada? While I was in United States, I applied for a visitor visa to Canada and received a 10-years multiple entry visa for Canada.

Can I apply for student visa to Canada and complete my studies?

Comment: There's nothing automatically disqualifying you under Canadian law, but the chance that they'll grant you a visa is probably very low indeed.  You will almost certainly be unable to convince them that you will abide by the conditions of the visa, since you have shown yourself willing to violate the conditions of your US visa. But questions about student visas are off topic here; the place for such questions is [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Of course you can apply. An approval however is another matter and opinion based as well as off topic. Tough luck, unfortunate your studies were derailed in the home stretch because of your illegal work but rules are there to be obeyed.

Comment: So what should be my next step? Can you explain me in this condition what should i do in order to complete my studies

Comment: You may have to look for alternative to Canada, maybe UK, Australia or elsewhere and transfer your credits. Don’t put your hope on Canada. Maybe it will be better to enter Canada on your current visa and then do a change of status to students visa because applying for a new student visa, you are likely to be denied.

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie UK and Australia applications ask about adverse info re:  other countries (visa refusals, bans, deportations etc.) and should OP attempt to enter Canada on the current visa, it could make things even worse. Any student application would have to be accompanied by a request to transfer the credits from the US university and the failure to comply with the US visa and its revocation may appear in or be attached to those records.

Comment: @Devendra patel If you were deported, where are you now? Can you complete your studies in your home country?

Comment: No matter where you end up, you're going to lose probably a significant chunk of your credits. Many programs have residency requirements, and/or just won't agree to transfer more than a year or two of credits from another program. You might try for an online US program, but most have some limited residency requirements.